# How to see matched files in the pattern matching option of a Jest execution?

Tags: testing, jestjs, pattern-matching

When I execute tests with Jest, you have these options:

[image]

If I'm in a React app created with `create-react-app`, I run the test, I use the `p` options, and I digit the pattern, the list of matched files is shown:

[image]

Instead, when I run Jest in a custom app I created (adding Jest manually), the matched files are not shown:

[image]

How can I see the matched files in Jest like `create-react-app` does?

This is my current `package.json`'s Jest section:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules",
        "."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `jest-watch-typeahead` package to the project, and then add this part to the `package.json`'s Jest section:

```
"jest": {
    "watchPlugins": [
        "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
        "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
}
```

(This is exactly what `create-react-app` is doing, and you can see this by ejecting the project with `yarn eject`).

If you're using a `jest.config.js` file, the `package.json` configuration will be ignored. Forget the `package.json` and add this property to the main exported object of the `jest.config.js` file:

```
watchPlugins: [
    "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
    "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
]
```